# How to prove $EN=\dfrac{AI}{2}?$ and $KN=\dfrac{CJ}{2}$? and $\dfrac{Area(ABD)}{2}+\dfrac{Area(BCD)}{2}=\dfrac{Area(ABCD)}{2}$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, quadrilateral, congruences-geometry

Given [image]

> \begin{aligned}
> \operatorname{Area}(E F G H) & =E K \cdot F G \\
> & =(E N+K N) \cdot \frac{1}{2} B D \\
> & =\frac{1}{2} B D \cdot E N+\frac{1}{2} B D \cdot K N \\
> & =\frac{1}{4} B D \cdot A I+\frac{1}{4} B D \cdot C J \\
> & =\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Area}(A B D)+\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Area}(B C D) \\
> & =\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Area}(A B C D) .
> \end{aligned}

How do you know $EN=\dfrac{AI}{2}$ and $KN=\dfrac{CJ}{2}$ and $\dfrac{Area(ABD)}{2}+\dfrac{Area(BCD)}{2}=\dfrac{Area(ABCD)}{2}$?

Comment: Does the geometry not make it clear that $[ABCD] = [ABD] + [BCD]$, where [X] denotes the area of polygon X?